# Circular Typing with Constraints

Tags: haskell, ghc

In the example below, I'm trying to make `foo` return its "expected" polymorphic output type. The idea is that `foo` returns a polymorphic value and an existential type, and then `bar` specifies the type of the tuple to be the hidden type. (Of course this only works if the type in `bar` is also existential, which is true in my case.) The following example compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Foo where

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Typeable

data HiddenType where
  Hidden :: (Typeable a) => Proxy a -> HiddenType

foo :: (i,HiddenType)
foo = (undefined, Hidden (Proxy::Proxy Int))

data Foo where
  Foo :: i -> Foo

bar :: Foo
bar = 
  let (x,h) = foo
  in case h of 
    (Hidden (p::Proxy i)) -> Foo (x :: i)
```

I really need a `Typeable` constraint on `foo`:

```
foo :: (Typeable i) => (i,HiddenType)
```

When I add that constraint (no other changes), I get these errors:

```
Foo.hs:20:15:
    No instance for (Typeable t0) arising from a use of ‘foo’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include x :: t0 (bound at Foo.hs:20:8)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance [overlap ok] Typeable ()
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Typeable.Internal’
      instance [overlap ok] Typeable Bool
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Typeable.Internal’
      instance [overlap ok] Typeable Char
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Typeable.Internal’
      ...plus 14 others
    In the expression: foo
    In a pattern binding: (x, h) = foo
    In the expression:
      let (x, h) = foo
      in case h of { (Hidden (p :: Proxy i)) -> Foo (x :: i) }

Foo.hs:22:35:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘t0’
      because type variable ‘a’ would escape its scope
    This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
      a pattern with constructor
        Hidden :: forall a. Typeable a => Proxy a -> HiddenType,
      in a case alternative
      at Foo.hs:22:6-24
    Relevant bindings include
      p :: Proxy a (bound at Foo.hs:22:14)
      x :: t0 (bound at Foo.hs:20:8)
    In the first argument of ‘Foo’, namely ‘(x :: i)’
    In the expression: Foo (x :: i)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I understand that constraints turn into arguments in core, so it seems to me that the issue here is that GHC can't handle pattern bindings for GADTs. If it could, I could use a recursive let to say something like:

```
bar :: Foo
bar = 
  let (x :: i,h) = foo
      (Hidden (p::Proxy i)) = h
  in Foo x
```

That should make the constraint in scope, providing the extra argument to `foo`. My intent here is that `h` contains some (hidden) concrete type `i`, which should be used as the concrete type for the polymorphic function 
GHC complains:

```
Foo.hs:19:8:
    You cannot bind scoped type variable ‘i’
      in a pattern binding signature
    In the pattern: x :: i
    In the pattern: (x :: i, h)
    In a pattern binding:
      (x :: i, h) = foo

Foo.hs:20:8:
    My brain just exploded
    I can't handle pattern bindings for existential or GADT data constructors.
    Instead, use a case-expression, or do-notation, to unpack the constructor.
    In the pattern: Hidden (p :: Proxy i)
    In a pattern binding: (Hidden (p :: Proxy i)) = h
    In the expression:
      let
        (x :: i, h) = foo
        (Hidden (p :: Proxy i)) = h
      in Foo x
```

The assumptions for my use case are that 
 1. `foo` computes `i` and the `HiddenType` simultaneously
 2. The value of the hidden type involves (at least partial) computation of the first tuple element. This means I do *not* want to call `foo` twice in `bar` (once to get the `HiddenType`, and once to use that type to bind the first tuple element).
Is there some way to make the definition of `bar` possible in the presence of a constraint on `foo`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Very little of this makes sense. Especially the last case, where you try to unify the type variable inside of `Hidden` with something else - precisely the opposite of what you can do with an existential type. The first case doesn't work because you need to select an instance so that the `Typeable i` constraint can be resolved for example, `let (x,h) = foo` must be `let (x,h) = foo :: (Int, HiddenType)`, but this won't work because you can't magically produce an into from inside `Hidden`.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to implement `Data.Dynamic`?

Comment: @user2407038 It sounds a lot like `Data.Dynamic`. The example is *really* chopped down, but at it's core, the question is about variable typing in ASTs. `foo` is like a `lambda`, where the hidden type is (expected) type of the variable. `bar` is like a `let`, which needs the type of the variable from a lambda, but then hides that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that `foo`s return value isn't actually polymorphic. `foo` itself is polymorphic but the returned value must exist at a specific type.  Unfortunately, the type you want to use isn't available yet and cannot be brought into scope at `foo`s call site because of the circular reference.  If we write out the definition of `foo` in pseudo-core, the problem is clear:

```
foo (@ iType) _ = (undefined @ iType, HiddenType...)
```

Here `@ iType` is a type argument.  We need to do foo's type application first (and the dictionary application, which is unused) before getting the `HiddenType`, so there's no way to make this work as-is.

Fortunately, there is a way to convince ghc that `foo` should return an actual polymorphic value:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}

module Foo where

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Typeable

data HiddenType where
  Hidden :: (Typeable a) => Proxy a -> HiddenType

foo :: (forall i. Typeable i => i,HiddenType)
foo = (undefined, Hidden (Proxy::Proxy Int))

data Foo where
  Foo :: i -> Foo

bar = 
  let (x,h) = foo
  in case h of
    Hidden p -> Foo (x `asProxyTypeOf` p)
```

If you're familiar with higher-rank types (e.g. the `RankNTypes` extension), you can think of `ImpredicativeTypes` as something similar, [except for data structures instead of functions](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Impredicative_types).  For example, without `ImpredicativeTypes` you can write:

```
list1 :: forall t. Typeable t => [t]
```

which is the type of a list that contains all values of type `t`, for some `t` with a `Typeable` constraint.  Even though it's polymorphic, every element of the list will be of the same type!  If instead you wish to move the `forall` inside the list, so that every element may be a different type `t`, `ImpredicativeTypes` will allow this:

```
list2 :: [forall t. Typeable t => t]
```

It's not a commonly-enabled extension, but it is occasionally useful.

The core for the impredicative version of `foo` is a bit different as well:

```
foo = (\(@ iType) _ -> undefined @ iType, HiddenType...)
```

You can see that this allows for `x` to be polymorphic as desired if you add an annotation to the `let`:

```
bar :: Foo
bar = 
  let (x :: forall i. Typeable i => i,h) = foo
  in case h of
    Hidden p -> Foo (x `asProxyTypeOf` p)
```

This allows you to delay the instantiation of `x` at the hidden type until later, when it's available.  You still need to box it up inside `Foo` or another `Hidden` though, as ghc won't allow the type to escape from under the first `Hidden` pattern match.

Comment: `forall i. Typeable i => i` is inhabited only by `undefined` and `list2 :: [forall t. Typeable t => t]` only by [], so I can't see this being useful. You should certainly not thing of ImpredictiveTypes as similair to RankNTypes - the latter cannot break working programs in any way, while the former will almost certainly do so. ImpredictiveTypes is evil and should be avoided.

Comment: @user2407038: sure, it's not that useful with just `Typeable`, but I imagine this is a severely cut-down example from what the OP wants to do.  I wouldn't enable `ImpredicativeTypes` unless necessary, but it seems to be exactly what the OP is asking about here.  Also, could you please provide an example of this extension breaking a working program?  GHC won't infer it by itself, so simply enabling `ImpredicativeTypes` seems unlikely to cause many problems except in contrived examples.

Comment: Also, impredicative polymorphism is simply a generalization of higher-rank types.  The best way to think of impredicative types is by explicitly manipulating the quantifiers (and it's the only way to use them in Haskell), at which point the relationship is obvious.

Comment: @JohnL This is *precisely* what I needed! I'm nervous about using `ImpredicativeTypes` (even before users's comments), but if that's what the extension was designed for...

Comment: @Eric: Well, the commentators do have a point in that you may actually want `Data.Dynamic`; with impredicative types the type of `foo`s first result is *entirely separate* from the existential type, whereas with `Dynamic` they'd be the same (or at least related) and you'd have to perform a cast after unpacking the `Hidden`.  I gave you the benefit of the doubt and provided precisely what you asked for, which is moving the type lambda into `foo`s result.  If you work with the explicit quantifiers and type lambdas, it's really much more clear what's going on.

Comment: @JohnL I tried out a solution using `Data.Dynamic` and it does indeed work as well. If I find myself in this situation in the future, how do I know which solution is best?

Comment: @Eric: they do very different things.  If `Data.Dynamic` works, that's probably what you want.  I wouldn't use `ImpredicativeTypes` unless you really need them.  I'm starting to sound like a broken record, but you should probably work out the types, with explicit quantifiers, so you can see how they're different in your case.